# get files from a directory that starts with specific characters

Tags: python

I am having this path `c:\testfolder\myfolder\`

And inside this folder i got these folders:

```
gr432d4dr
fr34q2sf4fd
grdddxwes
pl34scc
us4352fc
us4245
gr00mis
us994k
```

These folders contain **cpp** files inside.

What i want is to search ONLY from the folders that starts with **gr** and **us**

Here is my code which tried to search the specific folders:

```
def search():
    for filename in Path('c:\testfolder\myfolder\').glob('**/*.cpp') :  
        with open(filename) as f:  
            if "gr" or "us" in f:
              #do something
```

I put a print to see but seems like it's still checking all the folders

Comment: Use raw strings (`r'c:\testfolder\myfolder'`) to avoid character escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is not the filename, is the file object resource which let you access the file content. You must check the filename before opening the file.

```
def search():
    for filename in Path(r'c:\testfolder\myfolder\').glob('**/*.cpp') :  
        if "gr" in os.fspath(filename) or "us" in os.fspath(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:  
              #do something
```

You need `os.fspath` to get back a string from a `Path` object in order to use the `in` operator to search for a substring in the string.
Also note the `if` condition I've edited. Should be written in this way.

Comment: Still prints everything. Weird when i delete us and leave only 'gr' is gives me this error ->TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable